# Sink only saving an array via console and not via source

Tags: r, rstudio, sink

I am running this code:

```
max.print <- getOption('max.print')
options(max.print=nrow(countryaccepted) * ncol(countryaccepted))
sink(file.txt, append=TRUE, type="out")
cat("*************************\n")
cat("F-Test and T-Test Results")
as.array(HypothesisTesting)
cat("\n\n\n")
sink()
options(max.print=max.print)
```

The variable "HypothesisTesting" is a 3D array having dimensions 2 x 2 x 2 and contains values of type "double".

I am getting only following result in the file when I run the code via "Source"

```
*************************
F-Test and T-Test Results
```

But when I run it in "Console", I get following result saved in the file:

```
*************************
F-Test and T-Test Results

, , TTest

         H0 Accepted H0 Rejected
Ho True     98.68938    0.970427
H0 False     8.62801    1.310620

, , FTest

         H0 Accepted H0 Rejected
Ho True     100.0000     4.22076
H0 False     7.50504     0.00000
```

Why is the result not getting saved via source and why is it getting saved only via console?

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `print()` if you want to save the (console) output of an object via function or source.

```
*************************
F-Test and T-Test Results
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.01 0.01
[2,] 0.01 0.01

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] 0.01 0.01
[2,] 0.01 0.01
```

#### Code

```
arr <- array(0.01, dim=c(2, 2, 2))

max.print <- getOption('max.print')
options(max.print = 100)

sink("file.txt", append = TRUE, type = "out")
cat("*************************\n")
cat("F-Test and T-Test Results\n")
print(as.array(arr))                                   # wrap output into print()
cat("\n\n\n")
sink()
options(max.print = max.print)
```

Comment: If there were typos then why result is showing via console and not via source?

Comment: You need to use `print()` for what you intend. I clarified my post.